# Design concept on land scape

Tags: landscaping

I would like to know the meaning of design concept  , the type of design concept, and ways on which design concept are applicable .

Comment: I;m afraid you need to refine your question - its too broad and not very clear at the moment. 'Design concept' just means an idea for a design, any idea. The type of the concept is not something that can be defined because you've not mentioned a particular design concept. As for how a design concept might be applicable, without knowing the specific circumstances and the design concept in place, its impossible to answer, other than to say a design might be based around concealing ugly features, or practical in origin,  or simply to create a particular look, i.e. cottage style.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, a design "concept" is a document that lists all the pertinent information that will be used as criteria when a design product (plan drawing) is created. First the concept will contain the instructions of the owner, e.g. "This will be a memorial to my husband. It will be a place where people can sit and reflect on his many achievements." It will also list all the stakeholders who have an interest: local authority, neighbours, corporate interests, contributors, and so on with their special viewpoint expressed. It will contain perhaps a SWOT analysis of strengths, weaknesses, opportunities and threats. Anything that has a bearing on why you are doing this thing.

It might be a long list of items; they will help establish who is to do the design, in what time frame, the budget, special requirements. It will be the source document that gives the reason why you plan to put a red oak tree right in the middle and several benches for example. Whenever someone questions why you decided to put some Hostas in one corner then you just refer to the concept where it says it is the family's favourite plant. The concept is the narrative on which the final product hangs.

Comment: intriguing description - I've been designing gardens for 30 years in the UK, and half the stuff in your definition has been neither necessary nor desirable, though may well apply to design concepts in other areas - interior design, product design and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Design is the creation of anything by us humans.  There are rules that cross all subjects and then there are the inherent problems to be solved unique to  each subject. Design is a process to create something beginning with conceptualization then proceeding through a 'creative process' step by step that will bring a 'design' to light justified to become a design.

I am assuming this is about landscape design since you came to this site. Short story.  First year of my studies, we were given a project to design and give presentations. I remember someone mumbling about a creative process but I didn't get it. I always thought some people have a gift of creativity and others did not.

So I did this great project and great presentation and then my professors went into a meeting. The next day they called me in and sat me down and said, "You fooled us.  You did not do a creative process. You rationalized a project after the fact.  The creative process JUSTIFIES design concepts.  You were so good you were very bad.  We have decided that you now have a Directed Study to do. We want you to create a 'slide tape' presentation on the Creative Process". That is simply a class of one, me, to TEACH this process for 2 credits.  The effort was priceless.

I had to create a slide tape presentation (we only had the IBM 4341 in those days), those that created power point weren't even born yet!  So I sat down and outlined all the factors and how to organize my work according to this PROCESS I wasn't at all sure about much less, teach this process.

To make a long story short, the crux of this process is to list all the main problems.  For each problem one has to make themselves come up with 10 ways to solve that problem.  For each answer one needs to then come up with 10 ways to address each answer by thinking of all the problems that could arise.  And each one of those 10 problems  needs 10 answers to solve those problems.

Hey, sometimes, I'll allow 5 answers instead of 10.  It is a huge no no to 'jump' to the end product without going through this process. One makes their mind stay open by never jumping to the end product to imagine some end result or design... without going through this process that may take weeks.

When you have finished putting yourself through these 'hoops' of question and answers...a 'design' slowly emerges and you will know it is the perfect project or as close as one is able to get to perfect.  No one can or should just come up with a design without going through this process of making your mind jump through 'hoops', making oneself focus on each little problem, asking questions and having to come up with 5 or 10 solutions and then making oneself come up with 5 or 10 problems with each solution and then making oneself come up with 5 or 10 problems for each solution is simply using one's brain to its maximum potential.

The most incredible design takes shape.  One that is JUSTIFIABLE. A design that no one will be able to argue against very well at all.  Lots of designers who weren't taught this process jump to the final project with some Hollywood idea and then try to RATIONALIZE why those Hollywood ideas might work. Convince others of your innate design abilities and to sell your Hollywood idea. Great graphics and presentation skills can sell anything, even bad designs.

You'll be blown away by the final designs after going through this process. You have to understand construction, rules by the city/county for development, plants and soil of course, infrastructure such as irrigation, utilities, electricity, you'll have to get to know what your clients expect and how to educate them that part of their expectations are not going to happen and why.  The client DOES NOT KNOW BEST.  Other information you have to acquire; how many kids they'll have, what pets they want to care for, what they like in landscape and what they don't like in landscape; styles, what works now in their landscape and what does not.  Who will be maintaining the landscape, irrigation, lighting, coming up with costs and a final Master Plan complete with a page of construction details, a plant design, electrical design, irrigation system, lighting (powerful), specifications, perspectives of how the project will look, grading and drainage plan (critical)...not a small deal at all!

Once there is a signed contract, ha ha ha, that is when the real design begins.  As construction ensues, changes will happen (that wall is over the corner of the septic tank), and the entire design might change.  Listening to the subcontractors is again, critical; the rockery guys, the earth moving and grading guys, the nursery stock available, an ancient grave gets dug up!  Cad is nice but learn to do hand drawn plans, perspectives!  That is what sells, not Cad.  Cad is fun after a master plan has been approved.  Changes are so much easier than having to redraw by hand everything.  But hand drawing puts you INTO the project where Cad and the computer do nothing more than cut and paste.  Hand drawing puts clients in a safe frame of mind and allows them to become part of the design and they will pay more for stuff they can envision.

Landscape Architecture is one of the best subjects to learn as one is made to learn ALL sciences, construction practices, how to sell ideas, how to work with a clients through fruition of that project without 'breaking' up the marriage before the project is finished.  In fact, all of our clients became maintenance clients and constant little projects and constant big projects.  All the neighbors became clients.  I preferred residential over commercial.

I save BUDGET for the very last stages.  I pretend money is not a factor as I put myself through these 'hoops'.  When you get to where you see a design emerge it is very easy to scale down or even up to fit a budget.

Each project you do is unique has unique problems to be addressed.  Functional design is the only design.  Form follows function.  Beauty is in the functionality. Money does not at all make or break designs, ever.. Each project is fluid.  Things change every day, you will learn new information that you will have to address by 'jumping through hoops' again.  The more you know about every facet of the landscape, your client's needs, the more fantastic design.  Your conceptual plans are only to generate feedback from your clients.

Hand drawn plans are best for 'selling' or 'pitching' ideas.  CAD drawings look 'carved in stone' and that puts a client with his back against the wall and digging in his heels. The absolute best way to design is pull that client into the process.  I had one client, I shared this process, I would draw conceptual plans and then he would go redraw the plan.  He was very happy to be involved and the feedback was fantastic.  We went from a 20K budget to 110K.  An Italian Piazza.  In Washington in a nicer development but still a bit too much to recoup expenses when and if they sell their home. Incredible parties.  And this particular client was the budget manager for a huge firm.  His story starting at a 20K and ending up at 110K was a bit embarrassing for him at his parties.

The only way to be a fantastic designer is learn how to do this creative process and USE it every single time.  Your genius will be amplified every time you exercise your design abilities by making yourself jump through hoops.  Until you have actually gone through this creative process you will not quite understand. You just have to trust and jump through the hoops.  Pretty amazing to see what you are able to create! No, not just amazing, phenomenal.

They show  newbie Landscape Architects this slide tape presentation I made, 1978? to this day; 2 carousels of slides.  2 big screens.  I used cartoon type characters that looked like my class mates and professors.  That was a big hit.